# Need to fetch rows from MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I have records in one of the column of MySQL DB like :

```
ID                           Tax
1                      GST + PST + ABC 
2                      PST + GST + ABC
3                            XYZ
4                      PST + ABC + GST
```

These are stored as varchar in DB. Through my code I need to fetch records from DB that matches condition like tax = "GST + PST + ABC"

Currently I am getting only first record due to query:

```
Select * from table where taxes = "GST + PST + ABC";
```

But I want to fetch all records from DB in which above 3 names ( GST, PST, ABC) will occur irrespective of their positions.

So, I need records if I apply above condition:

```
GST + PST + ABC 
PST + GST + ABC
PST + ABC + GST
```

I am using MySQL DB, please let me know is there any function through which I can achieve above results based on my condition

Comment: Let this be a lesson to properly normalize your data.

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest something like this:

```
where taxes like '%GST%' and
      taxes like '%PST%' and
      taxes like '%ABC%' and
      length(taxes) = 15;
```

This tests the length if you want exactly those three codes.  You can also test the number of `+`:

```
where taxes like '%+%+%' and taxes not like '%+%+%+%'
```

Or if you want those codes and no others, then leave those conditions out.

This assumes that the names are non-overlapping (so there is no tax called "GS" or "ST").  If that is possibility:

```
where concat(' ', taxes, ' ') like '% GST %' and
      concat(' ', taxes, ' ') like '% PST %' and
      concat(' ', taxes, ' ') like '% ABC %';
```

Comment: Note that this would also return a row with `taxes = 'FOO + PST + GST + ABC + BAR'`.  (We could add `AND taxes NOT LIKE '%+%+%+%'` to exclude rows that have more than two plus signs.)

Comment: @spencer7593 . . . I still suspect that the OP really means at least those three codes, but I think I'm reading into it.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `OR`

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE WHERE TAXES = "GST + PST + ABC"
OR TAXES = "GST + ABC + PST"
OR TAXES = "PST + GST + ABC"
OR TAXES = "PST + ABC + GST"
OR TAXES = "ABC + GST + PST"
OR TAXES = "ABC + PST + ABC"
```

It's a pretty small list of things it could be, so I don't see a reason to get tricky with dynamically making complex SQL.

If data could be in other formats and you want to match like: `"GST + ABC + PST + ZZZ"` then we could do some work using `LIKE` AND `%`

Comment: Thanks I can use this but is there any shorthand function that I can use to make my code more readable and tends to be following standards.

Comment: I think because there are only 6 possible combinations I'd just use `OR`  like above.  You could try to dynamically make the SQL you'd like but that will be harder to maintain I think :)

Answer (score 1):

I would use

```
  WHERE NAME REGEXP "GST"
    AND NAME REGEXP "PST"
    AND NAME REGEXP "ABC"
```

Having said that, this sounds like a case where your data model isn't normalized enough. That is, you should be storing each tax-type in a separate row which will make MySQL operations a lot easier(just like in this case). It's not a good practice to store data in the form you have. I would attempt to store it this way:

```
ID  ID-sub  TAX
--  ------  ---
1   1       GST
1   2       PST
1   3       ABC
2   1       PST
2   2       GST
```

ID-sub may not be needed at all.